# How do I save the whole matlab gui panel?

Tags: matlab-guide

I can save a particular figure or an axes by using export_fig procedure. The command used is like the following:
export_fig(handles.Myfigure, filename). % This code is available on line

But I am trying to save a copy of the main gui (like a screen shot of the whole for record keeping). I guess this could work if I knew the handle of the main panel.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/getframe.html

Get coords of window and dimensions and pass it to this function.

Comment: I have the same problem - when I try with getframe all the controls (drop downs, buttons) and even text areas in the GUI just come out as black rectangles... do you have any other ideas?